# Is Josephus' account for the length of the Jewish War generally accepted as correct?

Tags: ancient-history, roman-empire, classical-antiquity, historical-accuracy, 1st-century

- In [Josephus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus)' [famous work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jewish_War) on the subject, the [First Jewish-Roman War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Jewish-Roman_War) is [depicted](http://www.livius.org/articles/concept/roman-jewish-wars/roman-jewish-wars-5) as lasting a full number of years,<sup>**1**</sup> inasmuch as it is presented as starting in the month of [Artemisius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Macedonian_calendar) (II Wars [14:4](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/josephus/war-2.html#S14.4)), and ending in [Xanthicus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Macedonian_calendar) (VII Wars [9:1](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/josephus/war-7.html#chap9)), with the [siege of Masada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Masada).
- Furthermore, a plain reading of the text itself suggests a span of seven years,<sup>**2**</sup> consistent with the (poetical) description of the same events, as related in the biblical book of *Daniel* ([9:24-27](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophecy_of_Seventy_Weeks)), highly praised by Josephus in his other writings (X Antiquities [11:7](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/josephus/ant-10.html#S11.7)).<sup>**3**</sup>

Now, though it is not *entirely* unheard of for wars to last an almost exact number of years,<sup>**4**</sup> it is not all that common either, thus leading me to suspect a certain artifice, be it stylistic, mnemonic, or religious, being employed by the renowned historian.<sup>**5**</sup>

**My question would be whether other authorities in the field have voiced similar concerns, and, if so, what were their doubts and conclusions on the matter ?**

---

<sup>**1**</sup> <sub>Since Xanthicus and Artemisius are consecutive months, roughly corresponding to the first two lunar months of the [Jewish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar) and [Babylonian calendars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_calendar).</sub>

<sup>**2**</sup> <sub>I am, of course, aware that modern scholarship proposes an eight year time span for the aforementioned events, based on coins found among the ruins of [Masada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masada) dating to AD 74, rather than AD 73; I can't escape, however, the feeling that seven is the text's intended reading, inasmuch as for an entire year-and-a-half to have passed from the Gorpaeus (autumn) of one year to the Xanthicus (spring) of the year-after-next, and for the ever-so-careful Josephus to have failed to whisper even as much as a single word about it, in order to alleviate any possible misunderstanding(s) on the part of his readers, seems rather unlikely, to say the very least.</sub>

<sup>**3**</sup> <sub>Further pertinent information on a possible relationship between *Daniel* and Josephus can be found in a 1994 article by Professor [Steve Mason](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Mason_(biblical_scholar)), from the [York University](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/York_University) of Toronto, published in the forty-first volume of the **Studia Post-Biblica**, entitled *Josephus, Daniel, and the Flavian House*, pages [161-191](http://www.academia.edu/11105056).</sub>

<sup>**4**</sup> <sub>Thus, the [Second World War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II), for instance, is generally reckoned as starting on September 1, 1939, with [Hitler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler)'s [invasion of Poland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_Poland), and, from an American perspective, ending on September 2, 1945, with the signing of the [Japanese Instrument of Surrender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_Instrument_of_Surrender).</sub>

<sup>**5**</sup> <sub>And by no means the only such (incredulous) artifice; indeed, in [yet another chapter](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/josephus/war-6.html#chap4), he not only has the [Second Jerusalem Temple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Temple) being burned down on [precisely the same date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tisha_B%27Av) as the [former](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon%27s_Temple) (VI Wars [4:8](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/josephus/war-6.html#S4.8)), but also attempts to provide an (arguably far-fetched) explanation for such a remarkable coincidence, by having the Jews themselves intentionally burn their own holy place to the ground (VI Wars [4:5](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/josephus/war-6.html#S4.5)), since the invading pagan Romans obviously could not have been familiar with, nor particularly interested in, either the events of Jewish history, or the exotic, non-Roman calendar according to which their commemoration was reckoned.</sub>

Comment: If there are 12 months in the year and if wars last a random amount of time, one war in twelve will end in the same month it started, and one in four will end in the same or an adjacent month.  So unless the opposing sides collude to avoid it, a war ending in about the same month (though a different year) than it started is not especially unlikely.

Comment: The Biblical book of Daniel was written somewhere around 167 and 164 BCE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Daniel#Dating )  The fall of Masada was 73-74 CE.  Therefore Daniel could not relate anything about the events.

Comment: Do we actually *have* alternate sources about the details of that war other than Josephus? Tacitus' Annals may have mentioned the beginning, but Annals ends before the war does.

Comment: This looks very relevant, will try to develop an answer if I have time: https://www.jstor.org/stable/23507728?seq=1

Comment: @jamesqf: The book of Daniel, as we have it today, saw its last revision at the hands of  [Theodotion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodotion), about the middle of the second century AD. Prior revisions (including Maccabean ones) are certainly not excluded, but, were it to have been *first* written, in its *entirety*, in Hellenistic times, would make it the *only* biblical book of *that* particular era *not* written in Greek, which is somewhat unlikely. A more detailed treatment of the whole matter can be found [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/revisions/106735/1).

Comment: @Lucian: I'm going by the Wikipedia dating.  In any case, excluding deliberate fraud by later translators (by using knowledge of later events to "correct" prophecies), it still has no relevance.  And of course Josephus can't be praising those later revisions, can he?

Comment: @jamesqf: I certainly wasn't implying that the text was frozen in ice until Theodotion. If it was edited in Maccabean times, as most scholars suspect, then why couldn't it also have been edited during or shortly after the Jewish war as well ? All we know is that the current version dates back to the mid-second century; what came before that is relatively unclear, even when the [Dead Sea scrolls](http://www.dssenglishbible.com/Scrollsdaniel.htm) are taken into account.

Comment: @Lucian: I think you've entirely missed my point.  Daniel is either irrelevant (being written before the event) or fraudulent, having been "edited" after the fact.  In either case, not a reliable source.

Comment: @jamesqf: Not if the edit(s) in question happened *before* Josephus penned (the Greek version of) his books on the subject, in which case, as a pious Jew, he would most certainly have been influenced by its text, which is considered sacred in Judaism. ([Note](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jewish_War) that the original AD 75 Semitic version did not survive, and the current one, according to Buth and Pierce, "must be considered a new edition, a complete re-working of the first writing and likely a considerable expansion").

Comment: @T.E.D.: "[Gessius Florus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gessius_Florus) became procurator: in his time war began." ([V Histories 10](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Tacitus/Histories/5A*.html#10)).

Comment: @Lucian - Oh, I see. I got confused because Histories was written before Annals, but covers a later period. OK....does it mention the end of the war? (checks...) It looks like it might have, but the books that would cover it are lost, so no it doesn't.

Comment: @Lucian: So you're saying Josephus might have fudged his history in order to make it accord with the religious text?

Comment: @jamesqf: Since Josephus was a pious Jew, he would have taken the biblical text as truthful and credible, and not have doubted its accuracy, **if** *Daniel* was indeed one of its sources. If not, then perhaps it was simply a literary and/or memorization device, inasmuch as historical reckoning is (also) a matter of convention (e.g., as I've already pointed out, as far as Americans are concerned, the Second World War ceased in August-September, whereas, for most Europeans, it ended in May; others reckon it as starting with the annexation of Austria, rather than the *Blitzkrieg* on Poland; etc).

Comment: @Lucian - Do we know that he was in fact a pious Jew *after* his capture by the Romans and defection to their side? He was eventually granted Roman citizenship, which seems unlikely for a practicing Jew in a Roman environment that was very hostile to Jews at the time (right after the war).

Comment: @T.E.D.: As you are probably aware, the Apostle Paul also had Roman citizenship. At any rate, I am not aware of any major changes in his belief system; at least none that transpire in his writings.

Comment: @Lucian - Paul went the other way: He was (probably) *born* with Roman citizenship, had a job persecuting Christians, then had a change of faith and changed sides. Rome didn't exactly look upon that change with favor.

Comment: @T.E.D.: His pious Jewish parents bought their Roman citizenship with money, which Vespasian, who ruled Rome during the latter half of the War, and a few years afterwards, considered [inodorous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pecunia_non_olet). Bottom line, at the end of the day, the Romans were deeply pragmatic, and the War did not change that.

Comment: @Lucian: As T.E.D. says, do we know whether Josephus was in fact a pious Jew?  (A brief overview of his biography suggests not.)  Even if he was, that just gives him a reason for inaccurately reporting events that he actually lived through.

Comment: @jamesqf: Unless I am either missing or misinterpreting something, his piety seems to transpire through all his literary works. (What gave you reason to suspect otherwise ?).

Comment: @Lucian: That he defected to the Romans?

Comment: @jamesqf: In the Jewish scriptures, piety and nationalism don't always overlap; especially not in the biblical books or passages associated with the fall of Jerusalem and its Temple prior to the [Babylonian conquest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_captivity), such as [Amos 7:10-17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Amos_7:10-17&version=NIV&interface=print), for instance. Josephus is simply adapting the well-worn theme, which, by then, was already several centuries old, to its contemporary Roman equivalent. (Was this the only reason, or were there others also ?)

Comment: @Lucian He didn't keep to the pact to kill himself in Massada. He lived as a house guest in Vespasian's house. That's kind of like abandoning the Warsaw uprising and moving in with Hitler. Nobody considers him a pios Jew.

Comment: @user6591: Judaism does not teach (let alone force) people to kill themselves, nor does it prohibit Jews from living with Gentile rulers (Joseph, Moses, Esther, Daniel, and his three companions come here to mind). I also don't recall him picking up the sword to fight his compatriots, nor worshiping foreign deities. He might not have been a patriot (post-Masada), but impious he certainly wasn't, as can easily be glimpsed from his writings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I doubt that anyone has been bothered by this coincidence because it's not terribly unlikely.

If there are 12 months in the year and if wars last a random amount of time, one war in twelve will end in the same month it started, and one in four will end in the same or an adjacent month.  So unless the opposing sides actively collude to avoid it, a war ending in about the same month (though a different year) than it started is not especially unlikely.

Comment: And some circumstances make some months more probable than others. Most wars don't start in the coldest months of the year because the roads could be closed by rain/snow. The hottest months are also bad for a campaign over a vast land because water sources can dry out. Harvesting season was necessary to feed your troops, etc. There is a reason the Romans dedicated March to the god Mars, it was a good time to wage war.

Comment: @Carlos Martin That's really a good point.  I wish I'd thought of it.

Comment: Statistically, they *should*... but do they *actually* ?

Comment: It's very easy to find wars that started and ended around the same time.  The US Civil War started on an April 12th and ended on an April 9th.  The English Civil War started on an August 22nd and ended on a September 3rd.

Comment: @GorttheRobot: Wars usually aren't particularly *civil*, so I am somewhat skeptic of your examples... Just kidding ! :-) That's pertinent information; feel free to edit it into the answer.